# spring mvc multipartfile extension validation using hibernate validator

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

Now I have following controller method:

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/member/createCompany/uploadImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Principal principal) {
           ....
```

I wan to validate file name of `MultipartFile file` that file exyension was `.jpg`

I want to have approximately following header :

```
public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") @Validated(DotJpg.class) MultipartFile file, Principal principal) {
```

Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

You can control the filetype in the file input, so the user can only upload jpg files.

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/jpg">
```

Comment: That doesn't eliminate the need for server-side validation.